# Is there an alternative to the spacy and NLTK sentence tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy-3

I'm trying to split some set of texts into sentence using the spacy and NLTK sentence tokenizer.

Here are the problem I'm having with them.

**NLTK**

sentence = "Gov. Abbot did something"
There should be no split here but NLTK split it into "Gov.", "Abbot did something".

**Spacy**

Spacy handled the above example very well, it did not split it.
But here is the problem I'm having with spacy again.

Sentence = "I got a D. Vance did something". This should be two sentences hence a split is required, but spacy did not split it.

Is there any method out there that I can you use to handle the two cases above?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can train your own sentence tokenization model in spaCy. See here, for example. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10210